# How to prevent datagrid from refreshing data?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Here's the scenario:

- Two toolkit data grids, side-by-side
- Grid A is readonly and cannot be changed
- Grid B's contents can be changed and saved using a save button under it

I need Grid A to stay the same until the user clicks the save button, regardless of any changes Grid B may or may not have.  When I bind to the property below both grids change when Grid B changes.  I want to avoid this.

What's the best approach to do this?  Both grids are currently binding to the below property:

```
    public EntitySet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities
    {
        get { return _entity; }
        set
        {
            if (_entity != value)
            {
                _entity= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SomePropertyChanged");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by using a DataGridTemplateColumn with OneTime binding. For example,

```
<sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Enabled, Mode=OneTime}"></TextBlock> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the binding for Grid A to OneTime.

i.e.

```
Text="{Binding Path=Age, Mode=OneTime}"
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I tried this, but it has the same issue.  OneTime sends data from source to target when first loaded **and** when the data context changes.  I guess that means my data context is changing?

Comment: How are you setting the context?

Comment: In the constructor of my view model: context = new SomeContext();

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of completely switching out the collection of SomeEntities that the Grid is binding to, maybe use an ObservableCollection, then update on a per item basis in the ObservableCollection. Then use the Mode=OneTime that Derek mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two EntitySets, one for each DataGrid. After saving, you have to update set binded to read-only DataGrid.